# RtlCopyMemory PUNICODE_STRING to WCHAR segfaults

Tags: c, windows, kernel

I am essentially converting PUNICODE_STRING to constant size WCHAR[] in my kernel driver, trying to avoid overflow. My approach works 99% of the time, but sometimes I get segmentation fault from the first RtlCopyMemory, most useful output from the debugger is something like:

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffc0016c0dd000, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff800adea85bd, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)
```

What is wrong with my approach (see below for example)?

```
typedef struct _MYRESULT {
 WCHAR Result[512];
} MYRESULT;

void myFunction(
_Inout_ MYRESULT *result,
_In_ PUNICODE_STRING s
)
{
 if (s->Length < 511) {
  // It is usually this RtlCopyMemory that crashes the kernel
  RtlCopyMemory(result->Result, s->Buffer, sizeof(WCHAR)*s->Length);
  // NULL terminate
  result->Result[(sizeof)WCHAR)*s->Length)] = 0;
 } else {
  RtlCopyMemory(result->Result, s->Buffer, sizeof(WCHAR)*512);
  // NULL terminate
  result->Result[511] = 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `result->Result[511] = 0;`?

Comment: @AlexD Probably, but that's an other bug that I have to correct... There is something wrong even before that.

Comment: `result->Result[(sizeof)WCHAR)*s->Length)] = 0;` has unbalanced parentheses.  Please show the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code copies too much data.

From [MSDN on `UNICODE_STRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (***emphasis*** by me):

> **Length**
>
> Specifies the length, ***in bytes***, of the string pointed to by the Buffer member, not including the terminating NULL character, if any.

From the calls to `RtlCopyMemory()` remove the `sizeof(WCHAR)`.

```
void myFunction(
_Inout_ MYRESULT *result,
_In_ PUNICODE_STRING s
)

{
  if (s->Length < (511 * sizeof * result)) {
     // It is usually this RtlCopyMemory that crashes the kernel
     RtlCopyMemory(result->Result, s->Buffer, s->Length);
     // NULL terminate
     result->Result[(sizeof)WCHAR)*s->Length)] = 0;
   } else {
     RtlCopyMemory(result->Result, s->Buffer, 512);
      // NULL terminate
     result->Result[511 * sizeof * result] = 0;
   }
}
```

Or less error prone (also following the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
#define RESULT_MAXIMUMLENGTH (511) /* This needs to stay smaller 
                                      then USHORT_MAX / sizeof * MYRESULT.Result. */

typedef struct _MYRESULT {
  WCHAR Result[RESULT_MAXIMUMLENGTH + 1];
} MYRESULT;

void myFunction(
_Inout_ MYRESULT *result,
_In_ PUNICODE_STRING s
)
{
  USHORT len = (s->Length < (RESULT_MAXIMUMLENGTH * sizeof * result)) 
    ? s->Length 
    : RESULT_MAXIMUMLENGTH * sizeof * result;

  RtlCopyMemory(result->Result, s->Buffer, len);
  result->Result[len] = 0;
}
```

Lesson learned: [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) helps.

Comment: `s->Length < RESULT_MAXIMUMLENGTH` is comparing the length in bytes to the max result length in `WCHAR` characters.

Comment: @eryksun: Indeed. Fixed. Thank you.